# How to catch unhandled error within Nodejs, https.get errno: -3001, code: 'EAI_AGAIN', syscall: 'getaddrinfo',

Tags: node.js, error-handling, https, get

In my nodejs function I call the sunrise-sunset api where I got suddenly the following error:

```
node:events:498
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^

    Error: getaddrinfo EAI_AGAIN api.sunrise-sunset.org
        at GetAddrInfoReqWrap.onlookup [as oncomplete] (node:dns:71:26)
    Emitted 'error' event on ClientRequest instance at:
        at TLSSocket.socketErrorListener (node:_http_client:442:9)
        at TLSSocket.emit (node:events:520:28)
        at emitErrorNT (node:internal/streams/destroy:157:8)
        at emitErrorCloseNT (node:internal/streams/destroy:122:3)
        at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:83:21) {
      errno: -3001,
      code: 'EAI_AGAIN',
      syscall: 'getaddrinfo',
      hostname: 'api.sunrise-sunset.org'
    }
```

Since I assume this is a sporadic DNS or network error, i want to catch this error and make a retry of this call after some time to prevent that this error makes my program to crash.
I already have an 'on error' statement but this was not called but simply stopped the program:

```
getSunInfo(url, cb) {
    var data = '';
    https.get(url, (res) => {
        res.on('data', (chunk) => {
            data += chunk;
        });
        res.on('end', () => {
            cb(JSON.parse(data));
        });
        res.on('error', (e) => {
            log.it(1, this.m, 'HTTPS error: '+e.errno+' '+e.message, 'Red');
            setTimeout(() => {
                log(1, this.m, 'now retry', 'Green');
                this.getSunInfo(url, cb);
            }, 5000);
        });
    });
};
```

How can I catch this error?